# SMTP not working in CI 3.0 while same code is working in CI 2.*

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, ssl, zoho

This is a big issue i'm struggling with, the thing is our application needs to send email, now we are relying on smtp, until 2.*(latest) email worked fine, but as soon as we ported app in ci 3.0 everything worked by smtp, here is error we are getting on ci 3.0 sample email

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: fwrite(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error
>   messages: error:140D00CF:SSL routines:SSL_write:protocol is shutdown
>
> Filename: libraries/Email.php
>
> Line Number: 2131
>
> Backtrace: **has nothing, it is shown blank, used bold text to specify that**

here is the issue i found on github [Error trying to send a mail](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues/3538)

i wonder if anyone is facing this issue, would appreciate help on this one

`source code`

```
function sendEmail($to,$subject,$body,$from = "My Company Name")
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $CI->load->library('email');
        $config['protocol']     = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host']    = 'ssl://smtp.zoho.com';
        $config['smtp_port']    = '465';
        $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
        $config['smtp_user']    = 'no-reply@my_domain.com';
        $config['smtp_pass']    = 'secret_password';
        $config['charset']      = 'utf-8';
        $config['newline']      = "\r\n";
        $config['mailtype']     = 'html'; // or html
        $config['validation']   = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not
        $CI->email->initialize($config);
        $CI->email->from('no-reply@my_domain.com',$from);
        $CI->email->to($to); 
        $CI->email->subject($subject);
        $CI->email->message($body);
        if($CI->email->send())
        {
            //return true;
            echo $CI->email->print_debugger();
        }
        else
        {
            //return false;
            echo $CI->email->print_debugger();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add the code you're using to send the email and also the config that you're using to initialise the email helper.

Comment: On third message down said `This is a networking or SMTP configuration issue, not a CI bug.`

Comment: Are you running on local host or live server. If your running on localhost make sure you have configured your sendmail on xampp, wamp, lamp etc. You need to do that before you can send email with codeigniter.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 i'm running on live server only

Comment: Can you add you email function that you use to send email and update your main post.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 added the code :)